# How to have "&" i.e and symbol in Android TextView

Tags: java, android

I want to have some simple text in textView..

Like...(android & java)

means I exactly require "and" symbol in `textView`

If I'm providing within TextView `android:text="Bakeries & Dessert"` in `textView` it's showing error in xml.

Can Anyone suggest me how to ignore special case characters & ," etc and have them in our `TextView` text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to set the text by code

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText("input");
```

using Html to encode/decode the text

```
Html.fromHtml(string)
```

Answer (score 62):

The layout files are just xml and the & symbol is not allowed by itself.

You will need to use `&amp;` instead

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Answer (score 43):

Use this :

```
   &lt; for < 
   &gt; for > 
   &amp; for &
```

Example:

```
  <string name="lessthan"> &lt; teste &gt;</string>
  <string name="link"> Puzzles &amp; code </string>
```

Answer (score 14):

The layout files are just xml and the & symbol is not allowed by itself.

You will need to use & instead of &

This will work fine

```
  <string name="contest_giveaways" formatted="false">Contests &amp; Giveaways</string>
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way to solve this is using **Unicode**:

1. set your text in your xml to

   `android:text="@string/myNameHere"`
2. In strings xml add the following line:

   `<string name="myNameHere">bakeries \u0026 desserts</string>`

voilá!

Answer (score 6):

Simply write it with amp followed by semi-colon as below:

```
android:text="Bakeries &amp; Dessert"
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a new string in `strings.xml` with the value of "Bakeries & Dessert".

Then, in the layout declare

`<TextView android:text="@string/your_string_value"></TextView>`

Later edit:

Adding an invalid character for XML in another XML file to circumvent the limitation will obviously not work. However, if you use Eclipse, when you add a new value in strings.xml, the characters like `&`, `<` and `>` will be automatically replaced by the HTML equivalents (`&amp;` `&lt;` `&gt;`).

Comment: This will not work because strings.xml is still an XML file and the "&" is still a reserved character in XML. An XML escape sequence will still be required if you move the declaration to strings.xml.

Comment: You are correct, I was not paying enough attention. When I added the string, Eclipse automatically changed `&` to `&amp;`.

Answer (score 2):

The layout file is an XML file and has certain restrictions on which characters may be used. However, you can use XML escape sequences to display characters which have special meaning to XML. In this case, replace the "Bakeries & Dessert" with the string "Bakeries &amp; Dessert" and you should get the behaviour that you require.

Comment: But what when the & comes from a database which I have no influence on?

Answer (score 0):

Another simply and easy alternate
Declare string in `string.xml` like this

Eg

```
<string name="terms_amp_conditions"><![CDATA[Terms & Conditions]]></string>
```