# how to use '&' symbol as string in android?

Tags: java, android

---

```
***
```

> <TextView
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
> **android:text="Calculator & Converter"**
> android:textColor="@color/black"
> android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

---

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have "&" i.e and symbol in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880338/how-to-have-i-e-and-symbol-in-android-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the text from string resources not a hardcoded string

```
android:text="@string/myString"
```

then set your text and add the & symbol as &amp;

```
<string name="myString"> Calculator &amp; Converter</string>
```